# How to set session storage inside angularjs directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code to store some values in angular session storage inside the angular directive

but i only get *NULL* , Can anybody help me

```
app.directive('myDirective', function (httpPostFactory) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: true,
    link: function (scope, element, attr) {

        element.bind('change', function () 
        {
            sessionStorage.setItem("ID","I'm a value saved with SessionStorage");
            console.log(sessionStorage.getItem("SavedString"))

        });

    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Is the element triggering the bind? you appear to be setting the item `ID` but then console logging `SavedString`, is this a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You save it as `ID` and get it as `SavedString`.
It should be

```
        sessionStorage.setItem("ID","I'm a value saved with SessionStorage");
        console.log(sessionStorage.getItem("ID"))
```

:)

Besides, I think doing that in a directive is not a perfect solution, maybe you could move it to some service.

Comment: you can mark it as a correct answer then, so that others know it's solved :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code too-

```
sessionStorage.ID="I'm a value saved with SessionStorage";
console.log(sessionStorage.ID);
```